# Error: k8s doesn't do anything after executing "kubectl create -f mypod.yaml"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am a beginner in Kubernetes and have been using the kubectl command to create pods for several months. However, I recently encountered a problem where Kubernetes did not create a pod after I executed the `kubectl create -f mypod.yaml` command. When I run kubectl get pods, the mypod does not appear in the list of pods and I am unable to access it by name as if it does not exist. However, if I try to create it again, I receive a message saying that the pod has already been created.

To illustrate my point, let me give you an example. I frequently generate pods using a YAML file called tpcds-25-query.yaml. The contents of this file are as follows:

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
name: tpcds-25-query
namespace: default
spec:
type: Scala
mode: cluster
image: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/kube-ai/ack-spark-benchmark:1.0.1
imagePullPolicy: Always
sparkVersion: 2.4.5
mainClass: com.aliyun.spark.benchmark.tpcds.BenchmarkSQL
mainApplicationFile: "local:///opt/spark/jars/ack-spark-benchmark-assembly-0.1.jar"
arguments:
    # TPC-DS data localtion
    - "oss://spark/data/tpc-ds-data/150g"
    # results location
    - "oss://spark/result/tpcds-25-query"
    # Path to kit in the docker image
    - "/tmp/tpcds-kit/tools"
    # Data Format
    - "parquet"
    # Scale factor (in GB)
    - "150"
    # Number of iterations
    - "1"
    # Optimize queries
    - "false"
    # Filter queries, will run all if empty - "q70-v2.4,q82-v2.4,q64-v2.4"
    - "q1-v2.4,q11-v2.4,q14a-v2.4,q14b-v2.4,q16-v2.4,q17-v2.4,q22-v2.4,q23a-v2.4,q23b-v2.4,q24a-v2.4,q24b-v2.4,q25-v2.4,q28-v2.4,q29-v2.4,q4-v2.4,q49-v2.4,q5-v2.4,q51-v2.4,q64-v2.4,q74-v2.4,q75-v2.4,q77-v2.4,q78-v2.4,q80-v2.4,q9-v2.4"
    # Logging set to WARN
    - "true"
hostNetwork: true
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
restartPolicy:
    type: Never
timeToLiveSeconds: 86400
hadoopConf:
    # OSS 
    "fs.oss.impl": "OSSFileSystem"
    "fs.oss.endpoint": "oss.com"
    "fs.oss.accessKeyId": "DFDSMGDNDFMSNGDFMNGCU"
    "fs.oss.accessKeySecret": "secret"
sparkConf:
    "spark.kubernetes.allocation.batch.size": "200"
    "spark.sql.adaptive.join.enabled": "true"
    "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true"
    "spark.eventLog.dir": "oss://spark/spark-events"
driver:
    cores: 4
    memory: "8192m"
    labels:
    version: 2.4.5
    spark-app: spark-tpcds
    role: driver
    serviceAccount: spark
    nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: ecs.g6.13xlarge
executor:
    cores: 48
    instances: 1
    memory: "160g"
    memoryOverhead: "16g"
    labels:
    version: 2.4.5
    role: executor
    nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: ecs.g6.13xlarge
```

After I executed `kubectl create --validate=false -f tpcds-25-query.yaml` command, k8s returns this:

```
sparkapplication.sparkoperator.k8s.io/tpcds-25-query created
```

which means the pod has been created. However, when I executed `kubectl get pods`, it gave me this:

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

When I created the pod again, it gave me this:

```
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "tpcds-25-query.yaml": sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io "tpcds-25-query" already exists
```

I know the option `-v=8` can print more detailed logs. So I execute the command `kubectl create --validate=false -f tpcds-25-query.yaml -v=8`, its output is:

```
I0219 05:50:17.121661 2148722 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /root/.kube/config
I0219 05:50:17.124735 2148722 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://172.16.0.212:6443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I0219 05:50:17.124747 2148722 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0219 05:50:17.124753 2148722 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0219 05:50:17.124759 2148722 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.22.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/9377577
I0219 05:50:17.132864 2148722 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status: 503 Service Unavailable in 8 milliseconds
I0219 05:50:17.132876 2148722 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0219 05:50:17.132881 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: e75a0286-dd47-4533-a65c-79d95dac5bb1
I0219 05:50:17.132890 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Content-Length: 20
I0219 05:50:17.132894 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2023 05:50:17 GMT
I0219 05:50:17.132898 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Audit-Id: 3ab06f73-0c88-469a-834d-54ec06e910f1
I0219 05:50:17.132902 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0219 05:50:17.132906 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
I0219 05:50:17.132909 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0219 05:50:17.132913 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: 7f136704-82ad-4f6c-8c86-b470a972fede
I0219 05:50:17.134365 2148722 request.go:1181] Response Body: service unavailable
I0219 05:50:17.135255 2148722 request.go:1372] body was not decodable (unable to check for Status): couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }
I0219 05:50:17.135265 2148722 cached_discovery.go:78] skipped caching discovery info due to the server is currently unable to handle the request
I0219 05:50:17.136050 2148722 request.go:1181] Request Body: {"apiVersion":"sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2","kind":"SparkApplication","metadata":{"name":"tpcds-25-query","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"arguments":["oss://lfpapertest/spark/data/tpc-ds-data/150g","oss://lfpapertest/spark/result/tpcds-runc-150g-48core-160g-1pod-25-query","/tmp/tpcds-kit/tools","parquet","150","1","false","q1-v2.4,q11-v2.4,q14a-v2.4,q14b-v2.4,q16-v2.4,q17-v2.4,q22-v2.4,q23a-v2.4,q23b-v2.4,q24a-v2.4,q24b-v2.4,q25-v2.4,q28-v2.4,q29-v2.4,q4-v2.4,q49-v2.4,q5-v2.4,q51-v2.4,q64-v2.4,q74-v2.4,q75-v2.4,q77-v2.4,q78-v2.4,q80-v2.4,q9-v2.4","true"],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirstWithHostNet","driver":{"cores":4,"labels":{"role":"driver","spark-app":"spark-tpcds","version":"2.4.5"},"memory":"8192m","nodeSelector":{"beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type":"ecs.g6.13xlarge"},"serviceAccount":"spark"},"executor":{"cores":48,"instances":1,"labels":{"role":"executor","version":"2.4.5"},"memory":"160g","memoryOverhead":"16g","nodeSelector":{"beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type":"ecs.g6.13xlarge"}},"hadoopConf":{"fs.oss.acce [truncated 802 chars]
I0219 05:50:17.136091 2148722 round_trippers.go:432] POST https://172.16.0.212:6443/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2/namespaces/default/sparkapplications?fieldManager=kubectl-create
I0219 05:50:17.136098 2148722 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0219 05:50:17.136104 2148722 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json
I0219 05:50:17.136108 2148722 round_trippers.go:442]     Content-Type: application/json
I0219 05:50:17.136113 2148722 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.22.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/9377577
I0219 05:50:17.144313 2148722 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status: 201 Created in 8 milliseconds
I0219 05:50:17.144327 2148722 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0219 05:50:17.144332 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: e75a0286-dd47-4533-a65c-79d95dac5bb1
I0219 05:50:17.144337 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Content-Length: 2989
I0219 05:50:17.144341 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2023 05:50:17 GMT
I0219 05:50:17.144345 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Audit-Id: 8eef9d08-04c0-44f7-87bf-e820853cd9c6
I0219 05:50:17.144349 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0219 05:50:17.144352 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     Content-Type: application/json
I0219 05:50:17.144356 2148722 round_trippers.go:463]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: 7f136704-82ad-4f6c-8c86-b470a972fede
I0219 05:50:17.144396 2148722 request.go:1181] Response Body: {"apiVersion":"sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2","kind":"SparkApplication","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":"2023-02-19T05:50:17Z","generation":1,"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:spec":{".":{},"f:arguments":{},"f:driver":{".":{},"f:cores":{},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:role":{},"f:spark-app":{},"f:version":{}},"f:memory":{},"f:nodeSelector":{".":{},"f:beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type":{}},"f:serviceAccount":{}},"f:executor":{".":{},"f:cores":{},"f:instances":{},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:role":{},"f:version":{}},"f:memory":{},"f:memoryOverhead":{},"f:nodeSelector":{".":{},"f:beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type":{}}},"f:hadoopConf":{".":{},"f:fs.oss.accessKeyId":{},"f:fs.oss.accessKeySecret":{},"f:fs.oss.endpoint":{},"f:fs.oss.impl":{}},"f:image":{},"f:imagePullPolicy":{},"f:mainApplicationFile":{},"f:mainClass":{},"f:mode":{},"f:restartPolicy":{".":{},"f:type":{}},"f:sparkConf":{".":{},"f:spark.eventLog.dir":{},"f:spark.eventLog.enabled":{},"f:spark.kubernetes. [truncated 1965 chars]
sparkapplication.sparkoperator.k8s.io/tpcds-25-query created
```

From the logs, we can see the only error "Response Status: 503 Service Unavailable in 8 milliseconds", I don't know what it means.

So I want to ask what may cause this, and how would I diagnose the problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe your namespace is different, can you try:

"kubectl get pods -A"

that should list all pods in all namespaces 

or just "kubectl get all" to list everything

Comment: @ehmad11 thanks for your comment，but I am sure the problem has nothing to do with namespaces

Comment: It's worth noting here that you're not directly creating a Pod but rather a SparkApplication custom resource.  Somewhere in your cluster is a controller that needs to read this resource and create actual Pods.  You or an administrator might look at that controller's logs and see if there are any hints.

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by comment but, it appears that you're creating a Custom Resource of type `SparkApplication` (`kind: SparkApplication`) not a `Pod`. You should be able to `kubectl get sparkapplications --namespace=default` to list the `SparkApplications` that you've created. If one already exists with the same name, you should be able to delete the existing `SparkApplication` using `kubectl delete sparkapplication/tpcds-25-query --namespace=default`. I'm entirely unfamilliar with Spark and this Kubernetes Operator it's CRDs so I'm unable to comment on the 503 from the backing service.

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple reasons for this, initially let’s check whether the pod is really created or not. Like `ehmad11` suggested use `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` for listing pods in all the namespaces. However in your case it might not work because your application is getting directly deployed in defaulf namespace. Regarding the error “Response Status: 503 Service Unavailable in 8 milliseconds” once you are able to locate the pod use `kubectl describe <pod>` for finding logs specific to your pod and follow the troubleshooting steps provided in this [document](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-kubernetes-service-503-service-unavailable-error/) for rectifying it.

**Note:** The reference document is provided from `komodor` site, here they have articulated each troubleshooting step in highly detailed and understandable manner.

Comment: @csbo check this [link](https://dok.community/blog/running-apache-spark-on-kubernetes/#:~:text=K8s%20operator%20installation.-,Let%E2%80%99s,-see%20how%20to) here they have mentioned the step by step procedure for deploying your spark application on kubernetes and troubleshooting steps if it encountered any errors.

Comment: @csbo this document from [lightbend](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/how-to-manage-monitor-spark-on-kubernetes-introduction-spark-submit-kubernetes-operator) also provides more insights on troubleshooting spark-submit and kubernetes-operator. Hope this will help you.